# SharePoint script editor webpart: javascript code for button

Tags: javascript, script-editor-webpart

I want to add javascript in Script Editor Web Part, to display a button and when user click on botton it should open google.com in new window.

Can someone help me with code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use content editor webpart for this

```
<a href="http://google.com" target="_blank"><input type="button" value="Link-button"></a>
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6303964/javascript-open-a-given-url-in-a-new-tab-by-clicking-a-button)

Comment: Have you found this useful @Brishal?